# col-lg-pull-12 or something else?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On mobile, area with prev/next page is on the left and avatar is on the right all with col-md-6.

[image]

All is good on mobile but on the desktop I want the opposite effect - avatar on top and prev/next area on bottom... all with col-lg-12. (12 because on lg they are in small col-lg-1).

[image]

When I try combine that two options to work together... col-lg-push-12 and col-lg-pull-12 didn't help me. I have no idea how to transform it like that. Meaby some Ajax or other trick?

[image]

**TEST IT HERE: http://betalivespot.pl**

At the top there is a standard option (bad location of avatar and prev/next on desktop). And under red bar there is test with col-lg-push-12 (still good on mobile but bugged on desktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your css:

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-push-12 {
  left: 0%;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-pull-12 {
  right: 0%;
}
```

Add some left/right in px to adjust like you want!

Then if you want to substitute avatar and previous page, you can try:

```
<script>
if(screen.width > 1200)
{
var div1 = document.getElementById ="id1";
var div2 = document.getElementById ="id2";
var content = div1.innerHTML;
div1 = div2.innerHTML;
div2 = content;
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to give ids to your divs

Comment: With your suggestion we're back to the same situation like in the first section on test page. Area with prev/next don't go down and avatar don't move up.

Comment: Good idea but working after page refresh. Is it possible to change it live?

<script type="text/javascript">
 if($(document).width() > 1200){
  var content=$("#id1").html();
  $("#id1").html($("#id2").html());
  $("#id2").html(content);
 }
</script>

Comment: Of course! I'm not sure about "if($(document).width()", but that's a way to do it. Don't forget to do the opposite if($(document).width() < 1200